# How do you evenly distribute columns in a FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a grid-like `FlatList` that is 3x3. I want the 3 columns to be distributed evenly based on the container (screen) width. In a normal view this would be accomplished by `justifyContent: 'space-between'`, but this doesn't do anything when used through `contentContainerStyle`.

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
  horizontal={false}
  scrollEnabled={false}
  numColumns={3}
  data={this.props.icons}
  extraData={this.props.selectedIcon}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
/>
```

As you can see the icons are all pushed to the left.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the React Native syntax, but have you declared the parent to be `display: flex`? Also, are the quotes needed around `space-between`?

Answer (score 51):

I solved this by passing a "columnWrapperStyle" to the FlatList:

```
<FlatList
    data={array}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    numColumns={10}
    columnWrapperStyle={style.row}
/>

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got a grid in `FlatList` like this:

```
const arr = ['1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1','1',];

<FlatList
    numColumns={3}
    data={arr}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
/>

_renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return <Text style={{flex:1}}>{item}</Text>
};
```

There is also a library for grids, if you want to get fancy easily:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid

Comment: So adding the `flex: 1` to the listitem component helps, but it is still not taking up the full width of the parent component. It is about halfway there with this addition.

Comment: Got it. In addition to `flex: 1` I also had to add `alignItems: 'center'`